# SharePoint 2010 Dropdown issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a dropdown control inside a webpart, when user select different item from dropdown list it does not reflect. the selection remains on first item.

Strange... it works in dev and qa environment properly but not in production. dropdown has autopostback true. it is inside an asp Panel. and having some checkbox lists inside a table ....no other functionality. any !dea? all environment have SP 2010 installed

Answer (score 0):

show us the code please.. It is a guessing game otherwise..

My gues is that you fill your dd inside page load event and do not check for postback there .. so you kind of rewrite it all the time . but why only on prod ... :)